# how to get Child View heights to be equal in GridView android programmatically

Tags: android, android-gridview, baseadapter

I am displaying a GridView in fragment.I have declared a gridView thr xml.I am passing values to gridView to Baseadapter.In Adapter Class,I am adding customView(xml file).

Based on dynamic Values,I am removing some image elements in some of child of gridView.When there is image,Height of ChildView is different ,compared to ChildView which does not contain image.

I want the uniform height to be obtained across all the child of gridView.There is no direct API to set height of gridView.

I dont Know is there anyway to set the height through xml declaration or through the properties of gridView programmatically.

So I am trying to get the get the elements of gridview programmatically in

```
public void onActivityCreated
```

{
.....
.....
reorderHeight();
}

```
    public void reorderHeight() {

    try {
        int size = acctgrid.getChildCount();//It returns 0

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            final View view = acctgrid.getChildAt(i);
            final ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = view
                    .getViewTreeObserver();
            if (viewTreeObserver.isAlive()) {
                viewTreeObserver
                        .addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1) {
                                    viewTreeObserver
                                            .removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                                } else {
                                    viewTreeObserver
                                            .removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                                }
                                Log.v("Max Height>>>>>>>>>>>>>is>>>>>>", ""
                                        + maxHeight);
                                Log.v("view Height>>>>>>>>>>>>>is>>>>>>",
                                        "" + view.getHeight());
                                maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight,
                                        view.getHeight());
                                Log.v("Max Height>>>>>>>>>>>>>is>>>>>>", ""
                                        + maxHeight);
                            }
                        });

            }

            view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(view.getWidth(),
                    maxHeight));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.v("Exception in Identifying Size>>>>>",
                "#####" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Please let me know how the retrieve the height of gridView programmatically,so that i can set it equal.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simple and dirty way for setting the GridView height manually.
declare child_height as global variable;

int child_height=0;

```
public class UsersAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User> {
    public UsersAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<User> users) {
       super(context, 0, users);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       User user = getItem(position);    
       if (convertView == null) {
          convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_user, parent, false);
       }
       TextView tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
       TextView tvHome = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvHome);
       tvName.setText(user.name);
       tvHome.setText(user.hometown);

       child_height = convertView.getMeasuredHeight();
       return convertView;
   }
}
```

So you need to calculate the number of rows for your GridView manually and multiply with this and set that value as your GridView height.

Comment: Let me Check,There is no Direct API to set height of GridView or or child of the GridView,Any Sample Code will be useful.